# Simplification of quadratic form

Tags: matrices

I have a quadratic expression of the following form:

$x = \boldsymbol{ a^T } \boldsymbol{ B } \boldsymbol{ a } $
where $\boldsymbol{ a } \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times 1}$ and $\boldsymbol{ B } \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times n}$.

Now, I have to bring $ x^2 $ in to a form of $x^2 = c \boldsymbol{ a^T }\boldsymbol{ a } = c \left\Vert \boldsymbol{ a } \right\Vert^2 $ where $c$ is then the scalar I have to determine, which depends still on $\pmb a$. Since, $x$ is a scalar I thought about the following possibilities:

1. $ x^2 = ( \boldsymbol{ a^T } \boldsymbol{ B } \boldsymbol{ a }) (\boldsymbol{ a^T } \boldsymbol{ B } \boldsymbol{ a })$
2. $x^2 = ( \boldsymbol{ a^T } \boldsymbol{ B } \boldsymbol{ a })^T ( \boldsymbol{ a^T } \boldsymbol{ B } \boldsymbol{ a })$
3. $x^2 = ( \boldsymbol{ a^T } \boldsymbol{ B } \boldsymbol{ a }) ( \boldsymbol{ a^T } \boldsymbol{ B } \boldsymbol{ a })^T$

and, since $x^2$ is also scalar maybe using $trace(x^2)$ and it cyclicality property. But so, far it did not work and I was not able to bring it into the needed form.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It doesn't make sense. $C\|a\|^2$ is a matrix and $x^2$ is a scalar. They can't possibly be equal unless $n=1$.

Comment: @user1551, thanks. Of course you're right. I made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible unless $B=0$. The reason is simple: if $B\neq0$, then $x^2=(a^TBa)^2$ is a fourth degree polynomial in the entries of $a$, but $c\|a\|^2$ is at most a second degree polynomial.

**Edit:** If $c$ depends on $a$, then it has to be defined as $x^2/\|a\|^2$ when $a\neq0$ and you are free to define its value at $a=0$.

By the way, if $B$ is positive semidefinite, you may consider the simplification $x^2=\|B^{1/2}a\|^4$, where $B^{1/2}$ is the unique positive semidefinite square root of $B$.

Comment: I think, I again forgot to mention, that $c$ is still dependent on $\pmb a$.

Comment: @bonanza If $c$ depends on $a$, you can simply define $c=x^2/\|a\|^2$ when $a\neq0$ and $c=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand why this is not possible. When assuming e.g. $c$ is again of a quadratic form:  $c = \boldsymbol{ a^T }\boldsymbol{ D } \boldsymbol{ a }$ then it would be of 4-th degree right?

Comment: @bonanza The original answer assumes that $c$ is a constant. If $c$ is a real-valued function of $a$, then as I said, you can simply define $c=x^2/\|a\|^2$ when $a\neq0$.